# YouTube Iframe API error in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am working on a site with a YouTube list of user uploads and am getting a few errors in IE8 that I cannot seem to debug. Site works fine in FF and Chrome. I also am not able to use firebug lite for some reason so debugging has been very difficult.

In IE8 I am getting: 'Expected ')' in regular expression' and 'Object doesn't support this property or method'

I have searched high and low and still get this error when using the example from the YouTube API documentation combined with the rest of my code. But I cannot narrow down where the issue is.

Here is the dev URL: http://dev.thenicestplaceontheinter.net/

Comment: That is *quite* a lot of code. Please reduce you code to a *small* self-contained demo, and put the source code on Stack Overflow, and the demo on a site like http://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: Here is a simple HTML page that demonstrates the problem: http://ehough.com/ie8-youtube.html